# Display database fields as checkboxes

Tags: php

I'm trying to display all my database fields like radio buttons. For example I have this database fields :

```
hostess_id
hostess_name_en
hostess_surname_en
... etc ...
```

I want to display them as radio buttons, in order to select them, then display data information only for the selected buttons.

How can I do that?
I have something like this:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
}
$dbname = 'db_up';
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die("Could not set $dbname: " . mysql_error());
}
$res = mysql_query('select * from hostess', $link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

  echo "<td><input type=\'checkbox\' name=\'hostess[]\' value=\'" . $row['hostess_id'] . "\'>" . $row['hostess_firstname_en'] . "<br />";

}


?>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are for selecting one option only. Don't you want checkboxes?

Comment: hah, i feel stupid.. yes checkboxes..

Comment: you can get field names with [mysql_field_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php), and I suggest not to use mysql_* functions its deprecated now, use PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, i could extract the names of fields... but how am i supposed o insert them into checkbox values/

Answer (score 0):

With PDO, It will get all fields

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE tablename");
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

With deprecated mysql_*

```
function mysql_field_array( $query ) {
    $field = mysql_num_fields( $query );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $field; $i++ ) {
        $names[] = mysql_field_name( $query, $i );
    }
    return $names;
}
// Example of use
$fields = mysql_field_array( $query );
```

Than you can loop through that array of field names and use the name with your check box.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes need a unique `name` or they need to be an array. A checkbox array would be appropriate for what you're doing:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='hostess[]' value='" . $row['id'] . "' />" . htmlentities($row['hostess_surname_en']) . "<br />";

}
```

This will give you a list of checkboxes with the hostess surname next to each.
Now, when this form is submitted to a PHP script, you will be able to access the selected row `id`'s with:

```
$selectedIds = $_POST['hostess']; // an array
```

`$selectedIds` is an array of the checked record `id`s.

I suggest using PDO or MySQLi for new code because the `mysql_*` library is deprecated.

Comment: Can you please see my updated code? there says :
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/form/form.php on line 22

Comment: Huh, sorry resolved it, but they're  displaying just the id's .. and not as a radio button... and i need fields to b displayed as radio b uttons.. am i missing something?

Comment: They should show as `checkboxes` not `radios`. `<input type='checkbox'>` cannot produce a radio button. Show the HTML that this produces.